# running webservice from IIS

Tags: asp.net, web-services, iis-6

Hello I am very new to creating webservice in .net.
I had created one webservice in .net It has by default one webmethod HelloWorld and another one is add method which i had created. Then i had build that webservice.
Now at second phase I had installed IIS
Then In Administrator tools--> IIS manager--> default website by right clicking i had created a virtual directory named as "trial" with path given of my webservice with all permissions.
my service has named as service.asmx.

Now the problem is when i right click on that service.asmx and browse it . it is showing me error such as

```
     You are not authorized to view this page

     You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials you supplied.
```

I had also tried of checking that "enable anonymous access " and also tried by uncheckable it but it doesn't work.
Even if I had also tried of checking Integrated windows authentication and also tried to unchecked it but it also doesn't work now I am bit tired of it .
I can't understand why it does not give me rights to run that web service from IIS
that web service can be run perfectly from studio 2008.
Please give me suggestions to run it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all can you please include your Web.config file? Also, did you make sure to set up permissions for the folder you created with IIS Manager? Iwould check that first